# Why $p_1\mid a \wedge p_2\mid a \Rightarrow p_1p_2\mid a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why $p_1\mid a \wedge p_2\mid a \Rightarrow p_1p_2\mid a$ where $p_i$ is a prime number, $p_i \neq p_j$ and $a$ is a integer?

I don't fully understand that.

Also, is it true when $p_i$ is something different from a prime number?

Comment: This is not true. Take $p_1=p_2=a$.

Comment: I edited the question to say that $p_i \neq p_j$.

Comment: For the second part of the question (non-prime $p_i$), you need still $p_1$ and $p_2$ to be coprime, as an example $p_1=2,p_2=4,a=4$ shows.

Comment: @Sil, thank you, below in the answer it's beem already said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**
Thanks to Dietrich Burde for indicating that a counter example is the case where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the same prime.  This answer assumes that they are distinct primes.

$p_1 | a \implies ~\exists ~r ~\text{such that} ~a = p_1 \times r.$

Therefore, $p_2 | a ~\implies ~p_2 | (p_1 \times r).$

Since $p_1$ and $p_2$ are relatively prime, this implies that

$p_2 | r \implies ~\exists ~$s$ ~\text{such that}
~r = ~p_2 \times s.$

Therefore, $p_2 \times s \times p_1 = r \times p_1 = a.$

A sufficient (but not necessarily required) condition is that $p_1$ and $p_2$ be relatively prime.  They don't have to actually be prime #'s.

Comment: But $p_2sp_1=rp_1$ is wrong for $r=s=1$ (the OP doesn't say that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are relatively prime).

Comment: But you agree that the choice $p_1=p_2=a$ is a counterexample to the statement? So you should need that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are distinct primes.

Comment: @DietrichBurde See my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now.